# How to solve the network error on axios api call?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am not sure why the network error occurs for some of the users  I got this error on sentry and some users email me about this.

[image]

Few other errors are too on the sentry for the same API call.

Error: Request aborted

Error: timeout of 0ms exceeded

Here is the code that fetches IP Address

```
const getIp = async () => {
        const getIpAddr = await axios.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
        setIp(getIpAddr.data.ip);
};
```

Is this issue related to CORS or any way to solve this error? For some of the users, it works fine.

Comment: Can you show the full detail of error ?

Comment: @TonyNgo Updated error details. I am using NextJs

Answer (score 1):

It's typical CORS issue. Server doesn't allow your client to gather information directly.

try this

```
const getIpAddr  = await axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
```

Comment: Any idea why that code works for some of the users?